# Minimum of MyProject Files needed

Tags: vb.net, git, visual-studio, dll, version-control

I am writing a very basic library in VB.NET

The library just contains classes and modules.

Now in built output I see this files

- Application.Designer.vb
- Application.myapp
- AssemblyInfo.vb
- Resources.Designer.vb
- Resources.resx
- Settings.Designer.vb
- Settings.settings

Since I've seen other libraries with only `AssemblyInfo.vb` file, I was wondering if I can delete the rest.
What is the minimum of files I need here for the lib to work correctly, since I don't have any ressource or setting?

Comment: I edited my question. It's not about the gitignore, since I use the Github gitignore for VS. I've seen many libraries in GitHub, without the files I wrote above, so since they are not in .gitignore, I was asking if I can delete them from the solution, or are they needed for the library to work properly.

Comment: These are the files you need to *create* the library.  The *use* the library you need the end-product, the DLL that you get when you build the project.

Answer (score 0):

All the files you listed are necessary for a vb.net library project. And these files are generated (in `My Project` folder) when the project created not the build output files. So you need to **keep all the files you listed** in order to develop and build your project locally.

And for the files of build output, you can add these files in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a project in VS, you select a predefined template that dictates what gets created.  People often become accustomed to seeing the superfluous objects that a given template creates and assume that those objects are mandatory and must be there,  However, much of it is not needed.

There is also the *Empty Project* template (the exact name of this template varies depending on the VS version used).

In VS2017, selection of the template would look like this:
[image]

This is a bare-bones project and the Solution Explorer will look like this:  [image]

As you can see, there are no pre-loaded references.  You will need to add them yourself.  About the only thing defined in this template is that you are using the VB language;  This project starts out as a WinForm type, so  go to the Project Properties->Application tab and change the "Application type" to "Class Library" since you want to create a library.

You may find it useful to start with an Empty Project and add the stuff you normally use and then export the project as new template (in VS2017: Project Menu->Export Template).  For more on creating termplates, see: [Creating Project and Item Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates)

Edit:  I just realized that I did not answer your real question about deleting the unused items.  I just did a test case and deleted the items under MyProject.  I received an error on deletion, but doing a clean/rebuild allowed me to proceed without issues.  I would recommend that you backup the project before attempting this on an existing project, but I saw no long term issues in deleting unneeded objects from MyProject.